# How to convert dd-mm-yyyy to ISODate format in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

convert datestring to ISODate format:
for ex:
   11-05-2020 --- >  2020-05-11 16:05:58.970Z

Comment: If your input string is just "11-05-2020", how do you know it was at 16:05:58?

Comment: in principal, you could use `datetime.strptime('11-05-2020', '%d-%m-%Y').isoformat()` -> `'2020-05-11T00:00:00'`

Comment: @MrFuppes Please do not remove the `python` tag from Python questions.

Comment: @khelwood: alright, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `datetime` module to convert between strings and datetime objects.

For example to read the string, you can prescribe what the format is

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> d = datetime.strptime('11-05-2020', '%d-%m-%Y')
>>> d
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 11, 0, 0)
```

Then using this datetime object you can convert to another string representation

```
>>> d.isoformat()
'2020-05-11T00:00:00'
```